# Lua local variable assignment

Tags: lua, variable-assignment, local

I have been looking at some Lua code recently and multiple times the author assigns a local variable, altering the local variable seemingly with the expected outcome of also altering the assigning variable as he does not do anything with the local variable after. Is this the case or do these changes not affect the original values.

Gene Construct

```
local gene = {}
gene.into = 0
gene.out = 0
gene.weight = 0.0
gene.enabled = true
gene.innovation = 0`
```

Code

```
function nodeMutate(genome)
if #genome.genes == 0 then
    return
end

genome.maxneuron = genome.maxneuron + 1

local gene = genome.genes[math.random(1,#genome.genes)]
if not gene.enabled then
    return
end
gene.enabled = false

local gene1 = copyGene(gene)
gene1.out = genome.maxneuron
gene1.weight = 1.0
gene1.innovation = newInnovation()
gene1.enabled = true
table.insert(genome.genes, gene1)

local gene2 = copyGene(gene)
gene2.into = genome.maxneuron
gene2.innovation = newInnovation()
gene2.enabled = true
table.insert(genome.genes, gene2)
end
```

Comment: your question cannot be answered without knowing in which scope relation those two code segments are. also your senteces are quite confusing: "the author assigns a local variable, altering the local variable seemingly with the expected outcome of also altering the assigning variable"  whaaat??

Comment: I'm sorry it's confusing, I'm having a hard time explaining it. The author seems to assign values to local variables, then edit these local variables without then assigning these local variables, as if these local variables are acting as pointers and changes made to the local variable will affect the variable that was assigned to the local variable. The code example I gave is from a function,  where he assigned a local variable gene, then edits a value within gene. The function then ends, with no other processing on the local variable gene.

Comment: paste the entire function so we don't have to guess. without context your code does not make much sense. some values are copied by reference in Lua. assuming that the section you name "gegen construct" is creating a local variable that is then put into table genome.genes you can then later of course alter that gene's values by using a reference like in your "Code" section.
Please read https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/ befor you continue

Comment: I've added the whole function, the purpose of the function should include changing the assigning gene's enabled to false but he only does this on the local variable, not the original.

Comment: without knowing what copyGene does (no code provided) this cannot be answered. but the name suggests that the function returns a copy of the provided gene. Therefor changes to gene1 or gene2 should not affect gene. But that's not 100% sure without having seen copyGenes implementation.

Comment: My question is whether changes to gene affect genome.genes[math.random(1,#genome.genes)]

Comment: as I said, I can't tell you because I don't know if copyGene returns a deep copy or just a reference of gene... if you don't have the code and you want to be sure print both genes. if its the same table you know that you're changing it or not. or second way: just change it and see for yourself... just try things dude, you cannot hurt anyone. that's the only way to learn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changes to `gene` may affect `genome.genes[math.random(1,#genome.genes)]` because `gene` is a reference. From the [Lua Manual - Values and Types](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.1):

> Tables, functions, threads, and (full) userdata values are objects: variables do not actually contain these values, only references to them. Assignment, parameter passing, and function returns always manipulate references to such values; these operations do not imply any kind of copy.

This means that when you assign a variable to an object you copy the reference to that object, not the object itself.

For example:

```
local a = {1,2,3}
local b = a
b[1] = 'a'
```

The table `a` now contains `{'a',2,3}` because `b` is a reference to `a`.

Comment: @AlexL but you realize that he wrote "may" affect? The name copyGene suggetst that it is not a reference...

Comment: @AlexL `gene` is a reference to `genome.genes`, but as @Piglet points out `gene1` and `gene2` most likely are copies. If you want to know for sure `print(tostring(gene), tostring(gene1), tostring(gene2))` if they are different memory addresses they are different objects.

Comment: to correct my comment it is a reference of course, but not necessarily a reference to gene :)

Answer (score 0):

From my reading of the code I'd think the following:

```
local gene1 = copyGene(gene)  -- local copy, distinct from original 'gene'
-- (modifications of 'gene1')
table.insert(genome.genes, gene1) -- add modified copy to 'genome.genes'
```

So I'd guess that `copyGene` produces a copy of `gene`, meaning that `gene` isn't modified (only `gene1`, `gene2`).  References to these are held in `local` variables and these references indeed go out of scope at the end of the block. *But* the modified copy is added to the list (/ array / sequence, whatever you want to call it) `genome.genes` which *does* produce an externally visible effect (because that variable – `genome` – comes in from outside).

My higher-level impression of the code is that `genome.genes` is a list of genes that may or may not be `enabled`.  Each run through this function randomly picks one of these `gene`s and if it is `enabled`, (1) disables it and (2) adds two modified `enabled` copies to the `genome.genes` (which may then be the base for new copies in later runs).